# Is there a way to query a document in elasticsearch from logstash using document id

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Here, there is a real time system which transfers text messages to a shared folder. There is also a ***filebeat*** which navigates these messages to ***logstash***, then logstash parses them and outputs to ***elasticsearch***. The problem is the content of some messages put in shared folder are wrong and the correct form will be sent after an interval and sometimes the correct form comes sooner that the wrong one. Each msg has a field  called counter and a wrong msg counter is smaller than the correct one.

Is it possile to query/search records of elasticsearch based on document_id each time a new message is received by logstash and check to see if correct msg have already existed in elasticsearch or the current msg is correct and should be replaced with the old one.

Note that to access each message, a defined document_id is used and can be the same for both correcnt/wrong messages.
document_id is like below:

```
output {

   elasticsearch {
     document_id => "%{my_id}"
       .
       .
       .
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`elasticsearch` logstash filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) which will allow you to get one document matching your query. In your case, you can query for an id and you'll get your document:

```
filter {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      query => "_id:%{my_id}"
      fields => { 
         "field1" => "fieldA" 
         "field2" => "fieldB" 
      }
   }
}
```

After this filter executes, you'll have `field1` and `field2` copied into the current event as `fieldA` and `fieldB` and you can run if/then/else tests on your event as you see fit.